# file attachment inside popup in Kendo UI grid row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to add file attachment inside popup for grid row? Instead of filename - "file attachment"

[image]

Comment: Not sure if there is a easier way. In the meantime this link may be useful. http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/BCBzS/17/

Comment: I like that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have the custom template for edit.

You can use something like this:

```
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  }
```

You can build your own form in the popup-editor element
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.template